# How to avoid Out of Memory issue in Expo App?

Tags: redux, expo, out-of-memory

I searched a lot on the internet also did go here https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/1155

and here https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/src/createPersistoid.js#L140

I can't understand it? whenever I open a listing page of records, it just pop up and I can't do anything

[image]

Comment: OOM exceptions are difficult to debug because they're commonly caused by a memory leak, and the code that throws the exception may have absolutely nothing to do with the leak. If it's a leak, you'll need to learn to use a memory analyzer.

Comment: I deleted the expo go app and reinstalled it. Everything looks good.